# Is there a classification of derived sets in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

A set $S$ is called a [derived set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)) if there exists a set $T$ whose limit points are $S$.

Is there a classification of which subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are derived sets?

It might be helpful to have a list of derived sets.  Here are some examples:

1. Any finite set.
2. Any perfect set e.g. Cantor set

Comment: As a quick guess, closed and without singletons.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote, this is a good question. I agree with William Elliot guess.

Comment: @WilliamElliot What is a singleton?

Comment: @alphacapture A singleton is a set with one element. I'm guessing that WillaimElliot means something like $1$ in $\{1\} \cup (2,3)$. Quick question though: do you want to include points in $T$ as limit points of $T$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derived sets are the same as the closed sets.  Indeed, let $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be closed.  Then every non-isolated point of $C$ is a limit point of $C$.  We just need to enlarge $C$ to make each isolated point a limit point.  There are only countably many isolated points (each is isolated by some interval with rational endpoints), so let us enumerate them as $\{c_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ (if there are only finitely many, the argument is only easier).  Let $$D=C\cup\{c_i+1/2^j:i,j\in\mathbb{N}\text{ and }j>i\}.$$

Clearly every point of $C$ is a limit point of $D$.  Conversely, I claim any limit point of $D$ is in $C$.  Suppose $(x_n)$ is a sequence of distinct elements of $D$ with limit $x$.  If infinitely many of the $x_n$ are in $C$, they form a subsequence whose limit $x$ must be in $C$ since $C$ is closed.  So we may assume that $x_n\not\in C$ for all $n$.  If infinitely many of the $x_n$ are of the form $c_i+1/2^j$ for some fixed $i$, then they form a subsequence which converges to $c_i$ so $x=c_i\in C$.  So, we may assume that $x_n=c_{i_n}+1/2^{j_n}$ where $i_n\to\infty$.  The requirement that $j>i$ in the definition of $D$ implies that $j_n\to\infty$ as well.  But then $1/2^{j_n}\to 0$, so that the sequence $(c_{i_n})$ of elements of $C$ also converges to $x$, so $x\in C$ since $C$ is closed.

Conversely, it is easy to see any derived set is closed (if $x_n\to x$ and each $x_n$ is a limit point of $S$, then you can approximate each $x_n$ with elements of $S$ to get a sequence of elements of $S$ converging to $x$).